# Outlook Add-In compose mode: modify + send scenario

Tags: outlook, office-js

## Problem we're solving

For many months we used `makeEwsRequestAsync` to update & send drafts right from the Add-In context. This approach is facing Outlook's cache mode limitations and forces us to retry EWS requests for unknown period of time before we can finish the process.
Considering real customers complains about processing time we have changed the flow and moved drafts processing to the backend.

Here's a schematic diagram of what're we trying to do - [draft message processing flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiYCT.png)

## What went wrong?

After shipping this change to production we faced 2 major issues that we're trying to investigate and resolve now. 
Here's some context:

- we've got Microsoft Graph access tokens stored on our side to access the API
- we're doing 12 retries within 45 minutes until sending error email to a customer
- error rate is about 5%

### Issues

#### 1. Draft is not found in the API

There are number of drafts that never gets persisted on the backend: [failed draft searches over retries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyBvd.png).
Increased number of NotFounds starting at 6 retry shows us that processing job was able to get an email for a while but it was sent by a customer manually.

#### 2. Draft has no sync_id in the body

We have tried using EWS on the backend a year ago to process emails on the backend, we had to revert as some of emails that we sent didn't match customer's expectations: random parts of email body were missing. Assuming that API synchronisation can take some time, we started inserting empty link to the email body using `office-js`'s `body.prependAsync`. It looks like this: `<a href="#sync-${syncId}">&zwnj;</a>`. By doing that we were able to verify that draft that we received through the API is synced to the point where user pressed command button. Unfortunately our 45 minutes for retries seems to be not enough to sync. [failed sync_id check attempts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJCRr.png)

## Things we want to understand and get some help with:

1. Is there a better way to know that email is in correct state on the backend?
2. Is it true that Microsoft Graph API and Outlook REST API are getting synchronised simultaneously? In other words - is there any value in using both APIs?
3. Is there Windows Outlook Desktop settings that can help in faster sync of drafts? (except of turning off the cache mode)
4. What is the expected worst case time to wait before we can get the draft on the backend?
5. Any other comments/thoughts on this

Comment: Just to understand this a bit better, can you explain the user scenario? I'm not entirely sure if you have to work with drafts at all, if you already have the access token why don't you just save the email body and save it from your server side using graph? Why do you need to access to the draft to send it?

Comment: For #1, it would help to know the end-to-end scenario. For #2, we would recommend using the Graph API when possible, but both the Graph and REST APIs access the same data. For #3 and #4, there is just cached mode and online mode. Outlook syncs the draft when it is able to (and only after the item is saved). As you pointed out, there can be cases where the draft won't exist on the server, like if the draft is sent from the client.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT end-to-end scenario is as follows:

- we're fetching draft on the backend
- we're ensuring that draft is synced to the point when user pressed Add-In's command button - this saves us from sending partially synced emails
- we're updating body with tracking pixel / tracking links
- we're saving draft details/attachments to our backend
- we're sending updated draft

Comment: @MaviDomates we can't use stored connection to send emails cause we can't get  all data we need to send from the compose window (attachments will be accessible only after the item will be accessible through the API). Also we won't be able to provide nice UX - we'll be able to close the draft but it will remain in the drafts folder, that can be confusing for users. Right now they can check either email is sent or still in retries loop by checking their drafts/sent folders.

Comment: We recommend using Graph API. As for the delay in finding the item on the server; its due to cached mode of outlook. There is no faster way to force sync than to switch from cached mode. Is the main goal of doing things server side and sending email to add tracking pixels to the email before sending?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT adding tracking pixel is not the only goal, we're doing few other "must have" processes - updating links in the email body, filling dynamic tags like `{company_name}`

Comment: Can these tasks, ones' being done on back end, be done on the client side before the email is actually sent? If so, it looks like what you would need is an OnSend feature where the add-in can do some stuff on the email after send is pressed and before it's actually sent out. This feature is already requested by others. Please upvote the existing request here [https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/10964871-add-itemsend-event-so-add-in-can-cancel-email]. Requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: OnSend feature is something that we really want, already voted for it.

Comment: We cannot share a timeline at this stage but we are actively working on the OnSend feature.

Answer (score 0):

How about skipping the drafts-collection step and getting the client to POST your back-end with a copy of the email themselves?

```
function sendit() {
  Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync({ isRest: true }, function(result) {
    var ewsId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
    var token = result.value;
    var restId = Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(ewsId, Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0);
    var getMessageUrl = Office.context.mailbox.restUrl + "/v2.0/me/messages/" + restId;

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", getMessageUrl);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
    xhr.onload = function(e) {
      // Send this to your server:-
      console.log(this.response); // <-- this is the complete email (excluding attachments though)
    };
    xhr.send();
  });
}
```